# cell setBorder in JTable changes nearby cells background

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection, nimbus

I've created a `JTable` with 4 columns that is populated with data from a txt file. Because of this, there are no validations for the datatype inserted in every cell. The 2nd and 3rd columns must be populated with "int".
I want to set red font to every cell from these two columns that do not contain an "int" value.

Problem: the background of the nearby cells is also modified. How may I solve this?

```
/**
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates and open the template
 * in the editor.
 */
package rdjcsv;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import static javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder;

public class MyCellRendererKO extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public MyCellRendererKO() {
        setOpaque(true); //MUST do this for background to show up.
    }

    public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
        javax.swing.JTabletable, java.lang.Object value, boolean isSelected,
        boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (isNumeric(table.getValueAt(row, column).toString())) {
            //setBorder(createEmptyBorder());
            setForeground(Color.black);
            setValue(value);
        } else {
            setForeground(Color.red);
            //setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED,1));
            setValue(value);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
…
MyCellRendererKO mcr = new MyCellRendererKO();
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(mcr);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first statement of the renderer should be:

```
super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
```

This will reset the renderer default properties before you apply your customization.

Also, there is no need for the `setValue(...)` statement as this will be done for you.